# UIActivityIndicator is not working correctly Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am including `UIActivityIndicator` in my `UIViewController`.
I need to bring a file from FTP using.

I have a button on my `ViewController`, upon clicking that button, download will start. I put a `UIActivityIndicator` (`aiReceive`) on my `ViewController`, That is appearing in stopped state on my view controller, but only animate upon completing file download.

I am making a iPad App in Xamarin IOS.

I added the Async Method, but i am getting the below error now. 
**The await operator can only be used when its containing lambda expression is marked with the async modifier**

```
public partial class FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        btnReceiveData.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            //BTProgressHUD.Show("Receiving Data...");    --> This Component is also not working,
             aiReceive.StartAnimating();
             await GetFileAsync());

            BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();

        };

    }

async Task GetFileAsync()
        {
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    aiReceive.StartAnimating();   /* --> Inimation is not starting at this point. Animation Start After Downloading file, download takes time, i want to show animation in the mean while.*/
                        using (WebClient ftpclient = new WebClient())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ftpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
                                string sourceFilePath = @"ftp://ftp.google.com/FileName.pdf";

                                        var FileDownloadStart = UIAlertController.Create("Info", "Data file received.", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                             FileDownloadStart.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(FileDownloadStart, true, null);

                                        //Downloading file from FTP.
                                        ftpclient.DownloadFile(sourceFilePath, "C:\");

                                        var FileDownloadAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Info", "Data file received.", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                                        FileDownloadAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(FileDownloadAlert, true, null);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                File.Delete(EpazzDirectory + AuditorId.ToString());
                                var ExceptionAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Exception", ex.Message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                                ExceptionAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(ExceptionAlert, true, null);
                            }

                        }
                }
            }  
            }

}
```

[image: Indicator is shown on the page all the time.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread, and that will prevent the changes you want to make to the UI from taking effect (in this case `UIActivityIndicator` spinning animation).

The best way to do this is using async/await like:

```
aiReceive.StartAnimating();

await YourFTPRequestAsync();

aiReceive.StopAnimating();
```

Here are [official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) on async\await and a [sample driven hint](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async) on how it works

Comment: I updated my code as per your suggestions, but getting error. 
"The await operator can only be used when its containing lambda expression is marked with the async modifier"

Comment: Yes, as stated in the official doc the `await` keyword can only be used in a method marked with the `async` modifier so `public override async void ViewDidLoad()`

Comment: Sorry, just realized you connected your request to a lambda. Correct `async` placement must be in the lambda so: `btnReceiveData.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: I added "btnReceiveData.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e)".
It fixed the error, but now when i click on the button. i got the following Exception Alert.
"UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread."

Comment: Because in your case you are trying to update UI from another thread, not the main. Just edit your code with
            `UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
aiReceive.StartAnimating();
            });`

Comment: Thanks for helping.
There is some change in download code also, I changed **ftpclient.DownloadFile** to **await ftpclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync**.
Because async method which I created wasn't helpful until it has a **await** in it.

Now its working fine.